# Bootstrap customizing accordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating accordions using bootstrap, each accordion uses the following div:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
```

and each header uses:

```
         <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">Heading</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>
```

using CSS, how can I style the text to be white instead of black? I could put `style="color: white"` inside the a tag of each header, but I have to use the accordion many times and all the headers should have white text. Which is the best way to override the default black text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use class selector to achieve the same. Refer the below css

```
<style>
.panel-title a{
   color: white !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked well for me. Additionally, currently I am changing the background colour as such: <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #00866C">. If I wanted to do this using CSS, could I add a class called "x" and change the background-color of x in CSS?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own class or you can use `.panel-heading{background-color: #00866C !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

`div.panel-heading h4{
   color: white !important;
}`

or make injection to set all

```
style="color: white"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to add a new class to avoid modifying bootstrap class.

But, if you want to set white color to all accordion use this CSS rule:

```
.accordion-toggle {
    color: white !imporant;
}
```